# How to bind two or more folder for sailsjs controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm creating a node_module which will add some new model and the controller to the sails app so I need to  merge the node_module model and the controller to the sailsjs model and the controller so that before sails js lift It will get the both model and the controller files.

dir structure:

```
sails app
  |
  |--- api
        |
        |---controllers
        |---models
        |--- app.js

node_module
    |
    |--- controllers
    |----models
    |--- index.js
```

When the sails lift It will load the node_module hook 
Now How I can merge the both files controller and the models in the index.js file before the sails lift

> Note: I have some foreign key also which will use the node_modules

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think working on the Gruntfile could help you achieve what you wish.